# Assembly: code fails after moving code block into a separate function

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

My code doesn't work when I separate a block of code into another function.  I haven't been able to figure out where the problem is.

A snippet of the working code is as below:

```
; Filename: bootloader.asm
... code omitted ...

call load_kernel    ; Load our kernel
call switch_to_pm       ; Note that we never return from here.

jmp $           ; Jump here - infinite loop!

%include "print_string.asm" 
%include "gdt.asm" 
%include "print_string_pm.asm" 
%include "switch_to_pm.asm"
%include "disk_load.asm"

[bits 16]
; load_kernel 
load_kernel: 
    mov si, MSG_LOAD_KERNEL ; Print a message to say we are loading the kernel 
    call print_string

    ;   This block will be moved into a function called disk_load
    mov si, DAPACK      ; address of "disk address packet"
    mov ah, 0x42        ; AL is unused
    mov dl, 0x80        ; drive number 0 (OR the drive # with 0x80)
    int 0x13
    jc disk_error       ; Jump only only if the carry flag was set

    ret

... code omitted ...
```

It doesn't work when I separate the code block for loading disk sectors into another function. The changes are as below.

```
; Filename: bootloader.asm
... code omitted ...

[bits 16]
; load_kernel 
load_kernel: 
    mov si, MSG_LOAD_KERNEL ; Print a message to say we are loading the kernel 
    call print_string
    call disk_load ; Code block moved into disk_load function
    ret
... code omitted ...
```

Here's the relevant file with the disk_load function:

```
; filename: disk_load.asm
disk_load:
    mov si, DAPACK      ; address of "disk address packet"
    mov ah, 0x42        ; AL is unused
    mov dl, 0x80        ; drive number 0 (OR the drive # with 0x80)
    int 0x13
    jc disk_error       ; Jump only only if the carry flag was set
    ret

disk_error:
    mov si, DISK_ERROR_MSG 
    call print_string

DISK_ERROR_MSG: 
    db 'Disk Read Error',0
DAPACK:
    db  0x10
    db  0
blkcnt: dw  15      ; int 13 resets this to # of blocks actually read/written
db_add: dw  0x1000      ; memory buffer destination address (0:9dd0h)
    dw  0       ; in memory page zero
d_lba:  dd  1       ; put the lba to read in this spot
    dd  0       ; more storage bytes only for big lba's ( > 4 bytes )
```

Comment: Try to run under debugger step by step to check which statement doesn't work

Comment: It works after I place [BITS 16] in the disk_load.asm. I thought I didn't need to since I already set [BITS 16] at the beginning of bootloader.asm.

Comment: The assembler needs to know which "bits" mode to use for every individual file that it assembles.  It won't remember this setting from one file to the next.

Comment: When using `include` in NASM it is just as if the file was copy and pasted at that point into the code. If you put `bits 16` at the top and in an include use `bits 32`, `bits 32` will remain the default setting until another `bits` directive is encountered.